# Proves or counterexamples in retraction and coretractions of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Any tip for proving or counterexamples that the following morphism of $\mathbb Z$-modules ${\mathbb Z} \to {\mathbb Q}$ is not a retraction and ${\mathbb Q} \to {\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z} $ is not a coretraction?

Comment: With the definition I'm familiar with, a retraction is a group, a subgroup, and a morphism. Namely with $H \subset G$, a retraction is a map $G \rightarrow H$ that is the identity on $H$. For your first question, the only thing I can guess is that the group is $\mathbb{Q}$, the subgroup is $\mathbb{Z}$. But then the morphism $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ makes no sense. Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the notion of splitting sequence ? Your question is equivalent to prove that $$\mathbb{Q} \not\cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$$

This follows from the fact that in $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ there are elements of finite order due to the factor $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$, but $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't contain elements of finite order.